# How to validate checkbox as checked only on specific page layout and without record type?

Tags: page-layout, checkbox, required

I wonder how I can accomplish that checkbox field will be reuqired on specific page layout. As I know checkbox fields can't be simply marked as required on page layout level. Is it possible to implement that without record types?

Comment: If you are assigning the page layouts to different profiles, then I would assume using profile names, you can have a validation rule to verify if the field is checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you looking for a decent workaround since like you mention it's not possible in a "regular way", so I will share two options that we used before:

1. Validation rule
2. Use a picklist field instead.

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox cannot be marked as required because a checkbox always consists of 
a value - either true or false at any point of time.

If at all you want to write a validation rule to say the checkbox should be always selected, you can do so using a validation rule. Assuming that to be your case, and that you only want it on specific layouts, you can write a validation rule here by utilizing profile name. In this case, you also need to make sure that you assign a particular page layout to a particular profile.

So let's say I have 2 page layouts and they are assigned to 2 different profiles, something as below and that I only want the validation rule to be triggered for Page Layout A.

- Page Layout A assigned to Profile PA (I only want validation rule for this layout)
- Page Layout B assigned to Profile PB

Then I will create a validation rule on my object something as below to throw an error:

```
AND($Profile.Name == 'Profile PA', my_checkbox_field__c <> TRUE)
```

This way, this validation rule will only get triggered on specific profiles which are assigned to that page layout.